# Dative pronouns in combination with "zu"

Tags: grammar-identification

If it is possible to use other dative pronoun or noun with "zu" then why the object of zu specified with "sich" only

> Die Phrase »sich einschließen« bedeutet »durch Abschließen der Tür niemanden zu sich hereinlassen«.

*<sup>source: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einschlieszen</sup>*

Comment: Because "sich" exactly matches zu intended meaning? So why then use a different pronoun?

Comment: _@ughitudhi_ Question title and body are unclear again, revise please. What exactly do you mean (give an example in English if you're unsure). Generally you should put more efforts in your quesitons (cite from links, descriptive links rather than just throwing the URL, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The word "sich" is the reflexive pronoun for 3rd person singular. It refers to a subject that only exists as a vague idea in the context, but this "somebody" in the context, who is locking the door to separate himself from the rest of the world is without any doubt in 3rd person singular. So, in this sentence, the reflexive pronoun has to be "sich". But in other sentences you can have other pronouns.

> Ich lasse niemanden zu **mir** herein.
> I let nobody in to **myself.**

Here we have a concrete subject, it is the word "ich" which is in 1st person singular. So also the reflexive pronoun has to be in 1st person singular.

Other examples:

> Du lässt niemanden zu **dir** hinein.
> You let nobody in to **yourself.**
>
> Der Mann mit dem schwarzen Hut lässt niemanden zu **sich** hinein.
> The man with the black hat lets nobody in to **himself.**
>
> Meine Tante lässt niemanden zu **sich** hinein.
> My aunt lets nobody in to **herself.**
>
> Diese Maschine lässt niemanden zu **sich** hinein.
> This machine lets nobody in to **itself.**
>
> Mein Bruder und ich lassen niemanden zu **uns** herein.
> My brother and me let nobody in to **ourselves.**
>
> Ihr beide lasst niemanden zu **euch** hinein.
> You two let nobody in to **yourselves.**
>
> Die Chefs lassen niemanden zu **sich** hinein.
> The bosses let nobody in to **themselves.**

These were all German reflexive pronouns.

Comment: In short "sich" means there is  only  reflexive variant ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be reflexive: Example: "Ich lasse niemanden zu ihm hinein" (I don't let anybody in to him)

Answer (score 0):

There is a *sich* in

> durch Abschließen der Tür niemanden **zu sich** hereinlassen

because it is meant to be a paraphrase of

> **sich** einschließen

*Einschließen* is not obligatorily reflexive. I assume the dictionaries added a separate entry for the reflexive use because of the side of the door the subject is presumed to be on.

> Er schloß sich in seinem Zimmer ein. *(er = im Zimmer)*
>
> Er schloß seine Schwester in ihrem Zimmer ein. *(er = außerhalb des Zimmers)*

Either way, it is always the object inside the locked room, with the subject being the one that locks the door.